# How to add PHI node to the beginning of each basicblock

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization

I want to add a phi node to each basic block that has more than one predecessors. For example, add a phi node before store. I'm quite new to llvm IR, I know there's some function calls like `replaceAllUsesWith()` can be used to do something similar. But I have no idea how exactly can I use it. Really appreciate any help!

```
 <label>:7:                                      ; preds = %6, %0
 store i32 999, i32* %3, align 4
 ret i32 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a phi node to the beginning of a basic block is dead simple: [Find the first instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#a46ef6115027606b67adcf4d28f3dac17) and [create a phi node before that instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html#ab0ff669b12c20c07137705c38872ec63). That creates a new phi after any existing phis, but before any "real" instructions. It'll fail of the basic block is empty, which I presume it isn't in your case. You have to call [addIncomingValue()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html#a089cccb6f231efee72abc76d0f9c695f) as appropriate.

I presume you'll then want to use the phi in that block. You can loop over [BasicBlock::getInstList()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#a76099f3fde625e6e75431b6afd7081ce) and check each instruction using [getNumOperands()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#addec638786f763d967811b45cb662f1f) and [getOperand()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#abe1de1520a21f77ac57cc210bf0fb0b4), and change the relevant instruction operands using [setOperand()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#a5fa9b8e1842b354f64c1ba6be0a4a17f). That is what replaceAllUsesOf() does, except that it replaces all uses, even those in your phi and in other blocks.